# Is entanglement the normal state of affairs in QFT?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

I was going to ask how QFT models entanglement when two particles are emitted from a common source

I realized that I was probably asking about how the electron field was being excited in such a way  that the perturbation was carried away from the source ,in the form of waves so that the "sum" of the waves was a known quantity(zero at a guess)

Is my initial take anywhere close to how this  situation actually plays out in the QFT model?

Comment: Your second paragraph/sentence is hard to understand. I'll try to rephrase your question and let me know if it's accurate. You picture that, in QFT, rather than having two entangled particles moving from a source, there are no particles but rather an electron field, which has in some sense equal and opposite excitations / bumps moving away roughly where the particles are? If you confirm this then it becomes more answerable to me.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @doublefelix I think you have very well understood  what I had in mind-except perhaps  that the "bump" represent the moving particles in my mind.The particles "are" the bumps and are not being  pictured by me as  "moving away from the particles".It is my attempt to understand the small amount I have heard of re QFT.Iam not attempting to "correct" any mainstream interpretation -just to "make some sort of sense" of what I have read about so far.